# How to use parameter in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

Use in xml this query

```
searchCategory1="
SELECT &quot;$1&quot;
FROM &quot;$2&quot;
GROUP BY &quot;$1&quot;
ORDER BY &quot;$1&quot;"
```

but error message
ERROR:  relation "$2" does not exist

how can i pix this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three mistakes visible here:

1. You double-quoted `$1` and `$2`, so they are not interpreted as parameters, but as an object name (they are [*quoted identifiers*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)).
2. You can use parameters only in [*prepared statements*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) or [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) code.
3. Parameters in queries can only be used in a place where a literal could appear, so they cannot be used for column and table names.
   You'll have to replace the placeholders *before* you submit the statement to the database.